# Do I need to free a variable in a struct?

Tags: c, memory, struct

I have created a struct, which contains a variable. The struct looks as follows:

```c
typedef struct ABC {
    int x;
} ABC;
```

Now I want to free the whole struct, do I need to free the variable first?

```c
ABC *p = malloc(sizeof(ABC));
p->x = 10;

free(&x);   // Is this step needed?
free(p);
p = NULL;
```

Comment: This is not C# code, please be careful in what you tag. Also your code wouldn’t compile. Always provide actual code.

Comment: Free what you allocate. Do not free what you did not allocate. You allocated memory and assigned a pointer to it to `p`. Free that memory by freeing `p`. You did not separate allocate memory for `x`, so do not separately free the memory for `x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>Assuming you meant `p->x` instead of `x`...</sup>

> ```
> free(&p->x);   // Is this step needed?
> ```

Absolutely not. Not only it isn't needed, it's also wrong. You cannot free something that is not a previously allocated pointer. The field `x` is an integer. Simple as that. In other words, in order to be able to `free()` something, you would have to allocate it first.